# Doxygen to parse Makefile

Tags: makefile, doxygen

How do I parse a Makefile in Doxygen . My dir contains *.c and *.h files which it parses correctly. But I am not sure how I can get it to parse Makefile correctly. Is there a special plugin for GNU makefile parsing that I can use.
I could not not file any info on this.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Have you added the makefile to your `INPUT` or `FILE_PATTERNS` configuration file setting? By default doxygen won't process makefile (see the extensions it does process by default by reading the comment above the `FILE_PATTERNS` setting in the configuration file).

Comment: Doxygen has no built-in support to parse Makefiles; it is also not clear to me what you want doxygen to do with the Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I would find it extremely useful if DoxyGen could parse a makefile.
The makefile is central to the build process and would be a very good place to
include an introduction to appear on the main page.

I tried to include it by calling it Makefile.mk and asking doxygen to include the .mk
extension in the input files list.

One of the difficulties which I would foresee is that the comments start with #, 
and, as far as I know, there is no multi-line comment block available for make.

I guess this would mean that a revision to doxygen would be needed to support this operation.

I pretty sure that this would be a really useful enhancement to DoxyGen which many people would find useful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i came across for shell scripts which also does not supported by doxygen. here is the solution [link](https://github.com/Anvil/bash-doxygen). But even for Makefile/Dockerfile which does not have any real extensions for doxygen to parse. I would recommended to have some unified solution with doxygen.