# Documenting variables used in makefile

Tags: makefile, documentation, doxygen

I maintain a fairly complex [makefile for Arduino](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile). This makefile has lot of variables that can be customized by the user.

I want to automate the task of generating documentation for all these variables.

The first thing that came to my mind was Doxygen. By after some research I found that Doxygen [doesn't support makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407016/doxygen-to-parse-makefile#comment13471955_10407016)

So what is the best way to document the different config variables that are available in makefile?

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a script, that reads the Makefile and looks for special comments. Same principle as with doxygen. Like:

```
### VAR:CC CC defines the binary of the C compiler
CC = gcc
```

Just build up some datastructures in your script and then dump them to whatever you wish it to be: LaTeX, Markdown, HTML, Textfile...